Zariski connectedness theorem: from analytic & topological viewpoint
Let $p:Y \to X$ be a proper, flat (see later why) surjective map between smooth connected complex varieties $Y,X$, esp. $X$ unibranch. Assume that there exist a Zariski open (esp. dense) $U \subset X$ over which every fibre $p^{-1}(x)$ is connected (resp. irreducible).
Then there is a topological version of Zariski's connectedness thm. (see eg 5.6 U5, in Algebraic Geometry II by Mumford & Oda, or 3.24 in Mumford's AG I: Complex projective varieties) that assures that then every fibre of $p$ (so not only over $U$) is connected.
The argument uses interplay of Zariski topology with complex analytic topology of induced map $p(\Bbb C): X(\Bbb C) \to Y(\Bbb C)$. Let's stick on fibres over closed points only, so focus on fibres of $p(\Bbb C)$.
The map $p(\Bbb C)$ is topologically/ differential geometrically a proper, smooth surjective submersion (... there are pathological cases with $p$ surjective, but not submersion; lets exclude these; guess to assume additionally flatness for $p$ would resolve it) as we can treat complex manifolds $Y(\Bbb C), X(\Bbb C)$ as smooth manifolds.
What I'm wondering about, cannot we by density of $\Bbb C$-valued points reduce the statements about connectedness & irreducibility of the fibres reduce to analogous statements about fibres wrt $p(\Bbb C)$? If yes, cannot we reasoning that way also deduce not only that all fibres are connected, but even irreducible?
I know that the latter cannot be the case, as there are concrete counterexamples with families where general irreducible fibers degenerate to reducible fibres. But this raises then the question where the in following presented "argumentation" - which if I'm not overlooking something implies even that the fibres irreducible - would concretely break down?
My point was why cannot we also argue here via Ehresmann Lemma? For proof see, eg Prop 6.2.2, Complex Geometry, Huybrechts.
If not, why? if yes, wouldn't this imply even stronger statement that all fibres are irreducible assuming fibres over $U$ are? (..see below why I think so)
Clearly, this requires some clarification as Ehresmann works in differential geometric setting, and says that such map $f(\Bbb C)$ as above is locally a trivial fibration in differential geometric setting.
Attention: As these local trivializations are given not complex analytically, but differential geometrically, ie there exist open $V \subset X(\Bbb C)$ (wrt smooth topol) such that $(p(\Bbb C))^{-1}(V)$ is diffeomorphic to $(p(\Bbb C))^{-1}(x)) \times V$. Note, that this completely forgets about complex structure of the maps.
But we still get as important consequence that this implies especially that all fibres $(p(\Bbb C))^{-1}(x) $ are diffeomorphic, and so homeomorphic (a priori wr analytic topology), esp the topological features like connectedness and irreducibility are consequently  preserved in all fibres.
Btw.: The historical side of the issue I would like to discuss here. See for details the marked "Remark" part there motivating essentially why I relate ZCT here with Ehresmann lemma.
This raises two questions:
(Q 1): Does this reasoning via Ehresmann give also a correct proof of above quoted Zariski connectedness thm? (of course only in complex setting)
The crucial point which confuses me here is that note, that ZCT is about connectedness, but the Ehresmann argument presented above seemingly implies irreducibility in complex analytic topology of the fibres of $p(\Bbb C)$ which are in turn dense in fibres of $p$.
Of course, note that the proof is about  $p(\Bbb C)$ in complex analytic topology,
but as Zariski-connectedness and complex analytic connectedness are equivalent we get Zariski-connectedness; compare with remarks after proof of above qouted (3.24) in Mumfords CPV.
(Q 2): The issue with irreducibility of fibres in light of the Ehresmann lemma appears more subtle as the above presented proof implies not only connectedness, but even irreducibility too, but on the other hand it seems to be "to strong" as usually families admit reducible members.
Here, we should maybe be more careful with two involved topologies:
Recall, a top. space is irreducible iff a dense subset of it is irreducible.
So again the irreducibiliy of fibres of $p$ is then equivalent to irreducibility of fibres of $p(\Bbb C)$ beeing dense in them. But here we should be careful, as wrt analytic topology such a fibre is almost never irreducible.
But we can simply impose Zariski topology of each fibre $(p(\Bbb C))^{-1}(x) $ as topology induced by subsets $(p(\Bbb C))^{-1}(x) \cap U(\Bbb C)$ where $U \subset X$ Zariski open, since as sets we have inclusion  $X(\Bbb C) \subset X$.
Note that Zariski topology is subtopology of finer analytic topology (...algebr functions are analytic).
So the question becomes if the homeomorphisms between fibers $(p(\Bbb C))^{-1}(x)$ with resp analytic topology given by Ehresmann induce continous (neccess bijective) maps wr Zariski topology. If yes, this would imply that if there exist a Zariski open $U \subset X$ over which every fibre $p^{-1}(x)$ is irreducible, then every fibre of $p$ is irreducible.
But this appears wrong; there are families where general irreducible fibers degenerate to reducible fibres and it is "natural" in algebraic geometry that families have some reducible members. So it would be unplausible to expect this. But then, what is wrong with my reasoning via application of Ehresmann lemma above which seemingly implies that all  would be even irreducible?
So my motivation is to develop better intuition how much "non algebraicness & pure topology" sits in connectedness & irreducibility of varying fibers. The at least for me the cumbersome point is that in most contemporary literature one deduces ZCT - a statement purely about topology -  as consequence of intrinsically  algebraic Zariski's Main Theorem resp. prorties of maps of Stein decomposition. And I'm wondering if this statement - which is purely about topology - cannot be deduced with "almost" pure topological methods.

If you assume proper and submersive, then of course you can argue in this manner.  The main significance of the Connectedness Theorem is that the morphism need only be flat and surjective with normal target.  This gives many consequences in the "not-necessarily-smooth" setting, e.g., the Connectedness Theorem of Enriques-Severi-Zariski, the Bertini Connectedness Theorem, etc.

@Jason Starr: Yes, that's with flatness assumption is not a supprise, as flatness may be regarded as a reasonable "algebraic" replacement of beeing submersive, eg Hartshorne's AG, III, Prop. 10.4. The crucial point is that it seems that although argueing via Ehresmann as sketched above imposes stronger assumptions to get connectedness, so ZCT gives fiber connectedness under much weaker assumptions, it makes no statement about irredubility of every fibre assuming there exist a dense open where all fibres are irreducible. And indeed there are counterexamples for this with assumptions of ZCT.

The point which confuses me a bit is that the presented argument via Ehresmann - if I not made a mistake - seemingly even imply that then all fibres are irreducible under given assumpions, that's about what ZCT doesn't say something. Are there "algebraic" versions of this? So something, which imposes even stronger assumtions than ZCT + that general fibre is irreducible, and implies that every fibre is irreducible? (...I'm happy here to work only over $\Bbb C$)

Sorry, replace "flat" by "proper".

Flatness is not the algebro-geometric analogue of being submersive - that would be smoothness. For example, a degeneration of a family of elliptic curves to a nodal curve is flat but does not induce a submersion on $\mathbf{C}$-points. In general, if $f\colon X \to S$ is a smooth and proper morphism of schemes with $S$ connected, then irreducibility of a single geometric fiber of $f$ implies irreducibility of all geometric fibers. In particular, there's no need to work over $\mathbf{C}$, or to assume any properties of $S$ in that case. Is this the kind of answer you're looking for?

@SeanC: Yeah, that was surely part of my confusion in order to develop better intuition how to "transfer" appropriately the "picture" from diffgeo to algeo. Could you maybe sketch to idea how to prove that as you wrote if $f:X \to S$ ($S$ conncted), proper smooth and it has one irreducible geometric fibre, then all geometric fibres are irreducible? (That seems to be exactly what I was looking for)

This is mostly just an expansion of my comment above. First of all, proper flat families $f\colon X \to S$ of curves can have irreducible general fiber but some reducible fibers, as you mention. For instance, a family of elliptic curves can degenerate to an arbitrary Néron polygon. The reason your (correct) argument with Ehresmann's theorem does not contradict this is that in such cases $f(\mathbf{C})$ is not a submersion. Zariski connectedness is interesting mainly because it works in non-smooth (and even non-flat) situations, as Jason Starr points out in the comments.
In fact, in general, if $f\colon X \to S$ is a smooth proper morphism of noetherian schemes such that S is connected, then $f$ has a single irreducible geometric fiber if and only if all of its geometric fibers are irreducible.
I don't know a complete reference, so I'll give the idea of the proof. Let $s$ be a point of $S$ such that $f^{-1}(s)$ is irreducible. If $t$ is another point of $S$, then there is a sequence $s=s_0, s_1, \dots, s_n = t$ of points of $S$ such that for each $i$, either $s_i \in \overline{\{s_{i+1}\}}$ or $s_{i+1} \in \overline{\{s_i\}}$. This implies that for each $i$, there is a morphism $\operatorname{Spec} A_i\to S$ with set-theoretic image $\{s_i, s_{i+1}\}$ such that $A_i$ is a complete discrete valuation ring. Thus by induction we can use base change on $S$ to assume it is the spectrum of a complete dvr $A$.
Now there are two cases:

$s$ is the closed point of $S$. In this case, the result follows from EGA IV_3, 12.2.4(viii), which only uses properness and flatness of $f$.

$s$ is the generic point of $S$. By EGA 0_III, 10.3.1, there is an extension of dvrs $A \subset B$ such that $B$ has algebraically closed residue field. We may base change from $A$ to $B$ to assume that the irreducible components of the special fiber of $X$ are geometrically irreducible. Let $X_0, \dots, X_n$ be the connected components of the special fiber of $X$; since $f$ is smooth, each $X_i$ is irreducible. By EGA III_1, 5.5.1, since $X_0$ is a proper variety it follows that $X$ admits an open and closed subscheme $X^0$ with special fiber $X_0$. Since $X$ is smooth and $X_s$ is irreducible, it follows that $(X^0)_s = X_s$. If $X^1 = X - X^0$, then $X^1$ is an open and closed subscheme of $X$ with empty generic fiber. Since $X$ is smooth, so is $X^1$, and this implies $X^1 = \emptyset$, i.e., $X$ has special fiber $X_0$, as desired.



What is EGA 0_III?

There are five published chapters of EGA: 0, I, II, III, and IV. Chapters I and II each take up one volume; III takes up two; and IV takes up four. Chapter 0, on the other hand, starts before Chapter I and is then augmented when necessary for the others. Chapter 0_III refers to the part of Chapter 0 that appears in (the first volume of) Chapter III.

Re, ah, thanks!

In last two lines: why smoothness of $X^1$ & emptyness of its generic fibre implies that $X^1$ is itself empty? A guess: There, when you write that "$X^1$ is smooth", you still mean tacitly as "relative smooth" over $S=\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ , right? And so especially flat,and then the fibre dimension stays constant. So it seems - if I understood your reasoning there correctly - that emptyness of $X^1$ only depends on demanded flatness of $X^1 \to S$ alone, right? Or did you there had in mind a different argument to conclude that $X^1$ must be empty?

Your guess is right. However, case 2 also requires smoothness to make "irreducible = connected". If $f$ is only assumed flat, then case 1 still works with "irreducible" replaced by "reduced and irreducible", while case 2 still works with "irreducible" replaced by "connected", each with the same argument. However, the locus of $s \in S$ such that $f^{-1}(s)$ is geometrically irreducible is neither open nor closed in general without assuming smoothness of $f$.
